# why can my gcc command not have -static parameter

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, static-linking

I usually use gcc to compile my C program, it works ok, but when I tried to compile static library with -static parameter it always failed. 
Although I tried some solutions on google, but it still didn't get fixed.

My command is as follows:

```
gcc mycode.c  -static  -L .  -lurl -lcap  -o mycode
```

The error message is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but when I remove -static it works very well.

Comment: My guess is you don't have a static libc library on your system.

Comment: Your command *can* have `-static` but then it *fails*

Comment: @melpomene where can I download the static libc please.

Comment: Why do you assume there is exactly one static libc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's `-static` linkage option directs the linker to ignore shared libraries
during the linkage. So it must find static versions of *all* the libraries required
by the linkage, including those that are linked by default, such as `libc`.

You have not installed the static version of `libc` (which would be `/usr/lib/???/libc.a`), so:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`libc.a` is installed by the `libc` development package. The name of the `libc`
development package and how to install it depends on your distro. E.g. On Debian
or Ubuntu, the package to install is `libc6-dev`; on Fedora it is `glibc-develop`.

But before you go to do that, hang on a tick. You said:

> I tried to compile static library with -static parameter it always failed.

```
gcc mycode.c  -static  -L .  -lurl -lcap  -o mycode
```

That sounds rather as if you just wanted to link your program with one or both
static libraries `liburl.a`, `libcap.a`, located in `./`, and thought you should
do it by passing `-static` to the linkage.

There is no need to pass `-static` to link your program with `./liburl.a` and/or
`./libcap.a`. The options:

```
-L .  -lurl -lcap
```

will direct the linker to search in `./` for either of the files `liburl.so` (shared library)
or `liburl.a` (static library) and if it finds one or other of them it will link your
program *with that library*. If it finds *both* of them in `./`, then it will choose the
shared library `liburl.so`. So unless you have `./liburl.so` *as well as* `./liburl.a`
then:

```
-L .  -lurl
```

by itself will link your program against `./liburl.a`.

And likewise for `-lcap`. No need for `-static`. The default shared library `libc.so`
will be linked automatically. The linker has no problem at all linking your program
with some static libraries and some shared ones. That is what is *already happening*
with your successful linkage:

```
gcc mycode.c  -L .  -lurl -lcap  -o mycode
```

assuming that `liburl.a` and `libcap.a` are the only candidates for resolving
`-lurl` and `-lcap` in `./`.

And even if you *do* have both `./liburl.a` and `./liburl.so` - and/or `./libcap.a` and `./libcap.so` - there is still no
need for a solution as drastic as a fully static linkage. You can just *explicitly*
tell the linker to find a particular static library if that's what you want, like:

```
gcc mycode.c  -L .  -l:liburl.a -l:libcap.a  -o mycode
```